# Between operator in sql for multiple value ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 5 different ranges data on a column I was to put filter on like

```
10-20 
110-120 
250-260
```

I am using below but its throwing incorrect results.

```
Select * from test where
testnumber between '10' and '20'
or testnumber between '110' and '120'
or testnumber between '250' and '260'
```

Could someone please suggest how I can achieve this or correct way to do this in SQL. Thanks

Comment: Can you show us input and output that is wrong?  Your SQL looks good to me.

Comment: Your numbers look like strings - you may not be getting the comparisons you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * from test where testnumber between ('10') and ('20')
```

Comment: Hah, Creating a table was not a option for me. I needed to do this select * from test where testname ='abc' and testnumber between (('10') and ('20') or testnumber between ('110') and ('120')
or testnumber between ('250') and ('260')). I needed to put them inside () to act inside a AND statement rathen than OR.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get your ranges into a table with `BeginNum` and `EndNum` columns you could do

```
SELECT * 
FROM test t
INNER JOIN Ranges r on t.testnumber BETWEEN r.BeginNum and r.EndNum
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if you can't create a table, you may have a few other options:

```
Select *
from (values(1),(15),(50),(115),(200),(255),(300)) test(testnumber)
where testnumber between '10' and '20'
or testnumber between '110' and '120'
or testnumber between '250' and '260'
```

or

```
declare @test (testnumber int);
insert @test values(1),(15),(50),(115),(200),(255),(300);

Select *
from @test
where testnumber between '10' and '20'
or testnumber between '110' and '120'
or testnumber between '250' and '260'
```